# Attempt to allocate character string giving me a segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c

[Screenshot of attempted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lZYd.png)

This function is pretty simple and is just assigning string values to an array after allocating memory to the array, yet whenever the function is loaded the program gives me a segmentation fault? Can someone explain as to why that is?

Here is a copy of my code:

```
char* generateSent(char ** noun, char ** verb, char ** adjective, char ** preposition, char ** 
article, int nounsize, int verbsize, int adjsize, int prepositionsize, int articlesize)
{
  char *sent = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);
  strcpy(generateSent, article[(rand()%articlesize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, adjective[(rand()%adjsize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, noun[(rand()%nounsize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, verb[(rand()%verbsize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, preposition[(rand()%prepositionsize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, article[(rand()%articlesize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, adjective[(rand()%adjsize)]);
  strcat(generateSent, noun[(rand()%nounsize)]);
  strcpy(generateSent,sent);
  free(generateSent);
}
```

Thanks for the input.

Comment: `generatedSent` is your function name, why are you trying to strcat stuff there?

Comment: `char *sent = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);` makes little sense. You are allocating space to hold 100 character pointers, rather than 100 characters. `char *sent = malloc(sizeof *sent * 100);` makes a lot more sense here.

Comment: I have updated it using sent as the string in the destination now instead of generatedSent, and I have updated the malloc, yet now when I run the code I get the response: floating point exception (core dumped). Can this be fixed?

Comment: once again, why are you do *strcat* into your function name? My guess that instead of *generateSent* you need to use `sent` which you allocated. Also you need to make sure that 100 chars is enough. And before doing firs strcat you need to initialize the *sent" string with '0' or use *strcpy* instead.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question to adapt it to StackOverflow rules.  As it is post, there are many ways in which your program can be failing, but having nothing more than a snippet of code impedes us to do the appropiate testing to the routine.

Answer (score 2):

You use function name in all *strcat*s. Unlike visual basic, it is invalid in 'c'.
So, you did several mistakes:

1. writing data into address where your function is allocated by strcat. Probably causes segmentation fault.
2. pointer 'sent' is allocated but not used. It is a waste of memory.
3. your function does not return any data.
4. free in the function destroys data before return.

I will re-write your code in a correct but untested way.

```
char* generateSent(char ** noun, char ** verb, char ** adjective, char ** preposition, char ** 
article, int nounsize, int verbsize, int adjsize, int prepositionsize, int articlesize)
{
  char *sent = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // sizeof(char) makes more sense, you allocate an arry of characters.
```

To do the very first write you either have to initialize the string:

```
  *sent = 0;
  strcat(sent, article[(rand()%articlesize)]);
```

or use strcpy

```
  strcpy(sent, article[(rand()%articlesize)]);
```

As for the rest you should do strcat into *sent* to add to the end of the
string.

```
  strcat(sent, adjective[(rand()%adjsize)]);
  strcat(sent, noun[(rand()%nounsize)]);

  ...
```

At the end you need to return the sent

```
   return sent;
}
```

The issue is that you cannot *free* it in the function. As soon as free is done, the data becomes invalid. As a result, freeing of the data is a function of the *caller* after the data is used. So, no *free* in the function.

Comment: Thank you so much you're a great help, that genuinely explained it to me better than any video on the topic I could find!